Variance and vol swaps backtest
I am looking to build a backtesting tool for variance and vol swaps. Would anyone have an idea if there is available data for it or am I better off backtesting it using vanilla options and replicating the product?

Do you have Bloomberg access?

A challenging project. Even with a replication, you would need some varswap data to check the accuracy of the replication. It could be very hard to get. And you would need extensive option data.

Perhaps the easiest way to go about this is to choose a particular model for the options market in question.
For instance, suppose the market is described by the following model:
\begin{gather}
dS_t = \sqrt{v_t} S_t dW_t \\
dv_t = \omega v_t dZ_t
\end{gather}
with $E_t[dW_t dZ_t ] = \rho dt$. So this is a lognormal model for the instantaneous variance (a very fancy name for it is the "1-factor Bergomi model") where $\omega$ is the "vol-of-vol" (actually the vol of variance).
Under this model the varswap strike is simply
$$
E_t \left[ \frac{1}{T-t} \int_t^T v_u du \right] = v_t 
$$
The volswap strike is not known in a closed-form / analytical solution. However, it is not too difficult to carry out a vol-of-vol expansion and to derive that the volswap strike is
$$
E_t \left[ \sqrt{\frac{1}{T-t} \int_t^T v_u du} \; \right] = \sqrt{v_t} \left( 1 - \frac{ \omega^2 (T-t) }{24} \right) + O(\omega^3)
$$
Hence under this model the convexity correction is
$$
\sqrt{v_t} \,\frac{ \omega^2 (T-t) }{24} + O(\omega^3)
$$
which I'm guessing is a metric or signal included in many a var vs. vol backtest.
The question is how to obtain $v_t$ and $\omega$: those can be obtained from the options market for $S_t$ by calibrating the model, and options data is readily available. If I am not mistaken, BBG provides calibrated parameters for SABR and Heston for some markets (eg FX). Not sure they support the Bergomi model yet though.
I have only written down the value of the swaps at inception. Once realized volatility has accumulated the expressions become slightly more complicated but still quite tractable (using a vol-of-vol expansion).
There are also so-called model-free approximations for the volswap, but that's another topic. Also, as you may notice the 1-factor Bergomi model implies a flat term-structure for varswap strikes and that the varswap strike term structure moves in parallel. That is not realistic, hence the 2-factor Bergomi model is preferable .
If my answer hasn't fully answered your question that's because entire papers/books can be written about your question as it is posed :)
